# Internet SSL Usage Statistics

Tags: statistics, ssl

Has anyone seen published statistics on SSL/TLS usage across the internet (i.e. servers using SSL vs. non-ssl enabled servers)?

Thanks,
Chris

Answer (score 2):

These two talks from [Blackhat 2010](http://blog.ivanristic.com/Qualys_SSL_Labs-State_of_SSL_2010-v1.6.pdf) (pdf) and [Defcon 18](https://www.eff.org/files/DefconSSLiverse.pdf) (pdf) are probably the best data you're going to get.

Comment: I did come across Ivan's slides (which are really interesting by the way). Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

[ssllabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/) has lots of good stuff.

Comment: Thanks, I think those are the slides that Jumbogram referenced above.